# concurrent.futures raises TypeError?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

In case someone else see's this same problem:

```
## The params should have been sent as a tuple
data = []
for file in files:
    data.append((file, loc, symbol, under_df))
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    r = [executor.submit(process_file, data) for data in data]
```

I want to use `concurrent.futures` to cut down processing time for a bunch of files. I am very new to `concurrent.futures`.

Here is the code:

```
def process_file(file, loc, symbol, under_df):
        print(file)
        # Load the data
        fut_df = pd.read_csv('{}{}fut/{}'.format(loc, symbol, file), index_col=0)
        # drop duplicates
        fut_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
        # Create expiry column
        fut_df['expiry'] = fut_df['contractname'].str.replace(symbol.upper(), '')
        fut_df['expiry'] = fut_df['expiry'].str.replace('FUT', '')
        fut_df['expiry'] = pd.to_datetime(fut_df['expiry'], format='%y%b')
        # Convert timestamp
        fut_df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(fut_df['timestamp'])
        # get all the timestamps
        times = fut_df['timestamp'].tolist()
        # There is a bunch of code after this

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    r = [executor.submit(process_file, [file, loc, symbol, under_df]) for file in files[0:2]]
```

> [<Future at 0x7fd65a5b1860 state=finished raised TypeError>, <Future at 0x7fd65a5dc6d8 state=finished raised TypeError>]

I tried changing the code to test out the problem:

```
def process_file(file):
        print(file)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    r = [executor.submit(process_file, file) for file in files[0:2]]
```

I still get the same error.

What could be the issue here? The `process_file` function works without a problem.

Comment: Can you catch exc and print something in you child process?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show `files` and I think `file` might be something else than you expect.

```
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor


def print_int(el: int):
    print(el**2)

lst = list(range(10))

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    r = [executor.submit(print_int, el) for el in lst]
```

This works fine and uses your example code without `files`.

Comment: `file` is a string file name. `wipro_1.csv`.

Comment: am I passing in the multiple arguments correctly?

Comment: In the last example you pass only a single arg so it should be good.

Comment: Found the problem, it is the data should be sent as a `tuple` and as many tuples as there are files. I will post the code.